# is it possible to have Web server and NAS on the same hardware microsever?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, web-server, network-attached-storage

I have a HP microserver proliant gen 8, and i want to know if there's a way to make this hardware work as NAS with freeNAS ... etc, and in the same time make it work as a web server with Centos Nginx ? please describe in steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but rather than attempting to virtualize on such limited hardware, I'd suggest just running CentOS to handle both functions. There's probably no reason to use FreeNAS here, as CentOS can serve as a NAS and is entirely capable of ZFS.

This would be the best use of the resources available to your ProLiant Microserver.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, and on Centos can i make auto-sync and functions of NAS? i would like to link all my device, is this a possibility ?

Comment: Autosync to what?

Comment: phones or pc to the NAS, like a cloud for example ...

Comment: I'm not sure that this solution will become a "cloud", but it *can* provide storage to your local network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Install virtualization. Try [Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2) or [ESXi](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads).

Comment: Chris thank you very much for you answer, don't know why all the people down voted me for, however can you please explain more the idea, because i'm a bit new in sysadmin stuff, also i prefer linux solution than Microsoft :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend ESXi for a ProLiant Microserver. Pretty poor hardware support for the storage controller.